# Integrates SmartHome actions with Conversation in one App?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I want to integrate conversation actions and Smart Home Actions in a app. When call app will 2 options :

1. Play a conversations game.
2. Control light, pan,...
3. A chatbot,...

Is it feasible? How I do it ?

Comment: I don't understand the use case for making it a single app. Why would you need or want a single app to be both a game and control your home?

Comment: i want a app can do everything. I found mega agent, it is beta.

Comment: Conversational Actions (for games/chatbots) and Smart Home Actions are distinct and currently you cannot create a single Action that incorporates both.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot create a single action which is a combination of a conversational action and a Smart Home action. These two actions would use different pipelines. But you can implement a server which handles everything on your end. On Google’s end, there will be separate systems for both kinds of actions.